# AD data import into SharePoint List

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory-import

I have a customer Web part that is using SharePoint List to show the user details including User Picture.

I need to import AD data into this SharePoint list, I was planning to export a CSV and import it in SharePoint List but have some challenge in it..

1. If a create a new attribute in AD to save the **User Image**, how can we get that into the list, with othe details
2. how to automate the whole process to update the list periodically

Using SharePoint 2013..

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Timer job** for automate the whole process to update the list periodically.

Get records from AD and Update SharePoint list.

You can use **Hyperlink or Picture** to store the picture

Comment: by hyperlink or Picture, you mean in AD attribute !

Answer (score 0):

You could use PowerShell to do this and then attach it to a scheduled task.
Use the AD cmdlets e.g.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties thumbnailphoto,samAccountName
```

You could store this information in a custom object (or a csv if you really want) and then add it directly to the list using a function.

[EDIT]Actually you don't need to store it anywhere. You could just add the byte array directly to the SP List. In theory it would look something like this:

```
Function Add-Item{
[cmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [string]$spWeb,
        [string]$spList,
        [byte[]]$thumb,
        [string]$samAccountName
    )
    $web = Get-SPWeb $spWeb
    $list = $web.lists[$spList]
    $item = $list.Items.Add()
    $item["ColumnA"] = $samAccountName
    $item.Attachments.Add("$samAccountName.jpg", $thumb)
    $item.Update()
    $web.dispose()
}
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties thumbnailphoto
foreach ($i in $users) {
    Add-Item "http://sharepoint" "Documents" $i.thumbnailphoto $i.samAccountName
}
```

Comment: could CSV get the Picture from the AD !

Comment: Store it in a folder...

Comment: then how can we upload it in list among the other details

Comment: thinking about it there is no reason to use a csv or the file system. See my edit.